# Not receiving emails fromCakeMail

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cakephp

I have a weird problem using CakePHP/CakeMail.

I try to send an email for my gmail from the website.

I don't get the email, but I don't get any error either. 
The form send the message. The log don't hit anything. Passwords and emails are ok, so what could be wrong?

Here are the codes.

email.php

```
public $mymail = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('xpto@domain.com.br' => 'YourName'),
    'sender' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mygmailpassword',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
    'emailFormat' => 'both'
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'returnPath' => 'xpto@domain.com.br',
    'additionalParams' => '-f'.'xpto@domain.com.br',
    'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

PagesController.php

```
public function admin_send_contato() {

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if(!isset($this->data['email'])){
      $this->data['assunto'] = 'Assunto';
    }

    $email = new CakeEmail('mymail');
    $this->Email->return = 'my@gmail.com';
    $email->from(array('xpto@domain.com.br' => 'John Doe'))

    ->to('my@gmail.com')
    ->subject($this->data['subject'])
    ->replyTo($this->data['email'])
    ->send("Name: ".$this->request->data['name']."\nPhone: ".$this->request->data['phone']."\nE-mail: ".$this->request->data['email']."\nMessage: ".$this->request->data['message']);

    echo json_encode('ok');
  }

    $this->autoRender = false;
  }
```

I don't create the site and never used Cake before. 
I have no idea what is the problem.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: did you grant access to your app like described in this page?https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Hey. I did not, but changed it now and still no success. =/. Interestig: i didn't see see this setup anywhere before.

Comment: silly question: do you get the 'ok' message?

Comment: @arilia yes, I doooo. That is the weirdest thing. Everyhing looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a third party solution to send transactional and marketing emails. Sendgrid is an option and they have documentation to integrate in CakePHP; https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/cakephp.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I am just a freela in this project. No budget for third parties solutions... =/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken SendGrid allows 12k emails a month for free.